# How to create legend colors based on labels/unique classes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making pie charts for 7 different samples. For each sample 1 pie chart is made.

I have a total list of 207 unique classes (each row is 1 class) and for each sample I want to plot the top 8 classes on a pie chart. Thus the dataset of each sample consists of 8 different "classes" with a numerical value. To plot the pie chart, I extract the 8 classes with the highest numerical value for that sample. Some classes between the samples overlap while others are only found in the top 8 in a few samples. Image of such a pie chart (legend labels are classes):

[image: pie chart]

Now for each pie chart I make, I use the same color codes:

```
classgraph, texts=plt.pie(df["Col A"],colors=("#FFA500","#6A5ACD","#AE0C0C","#1E90FF","#228B22","#B4B9B3","#7D7D7C","000000")) 
plt.title(".......",fontsize=20)
plt.legend(classgraph,df["Col A"],bbox_to_anchor=(0.9,0.87), fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

I use this code (the df changes between samples) for each of the 7 different pie charts, so the same 8 colors are used for each of the pie charts, regardless of the classes. So the classes with the highest numerical value always have color code #FFA500, regardless of which class it is. If class 1 has the highest value in sample 1, it has color code FFA500, but if class 3 has the highest value in sample 2, it ALSO has color code FFA500. When comparing the pie charts this can be confusing.

However, I would like to have that each class has a unique color. So that class 1 has color X over all of the pie charts, regardless of it numerical value. I could do this by hand, but that is rather tedious. Is there an easy way to do this that can be directly implemented in my code to create the figures? I'd like to keep this code format.

Comment: Have a look at matplotlib colormaps https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

But you could just generate the colors in a deterministic way manually, they are just hex values

Comment: I will check it out, thanks! I could do it manually yes, but then I have to check for each sample the top 8 classes and assign the right color code to each of them correctly each time.

Comment: In a way, each unique class (=row) should have its own color code.

Comment: It's almost impossible to get 207 distinguishable colors, since the human brain is trained to see similarities. Maybe you can come up with a [mcve] that uses 10 unique elements, with 3 pies that each use a subset of those. This would be the case that people would be interested in and hence someone might be more motivated to answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried to add an example DF before but I couldn't get it to work. When posted the layout of the DF changed completely. That's why I tried to describe it in this way

Comment: Feel free to ping me (using @username notation), once you sorted out the formatting problems.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I will!